# How to Marshal a map contains struct as the intout/output parameter when C# calls function from c++?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

Here is the function define in c++:

```
struct StructDefineInCPlus
{
    const wchar_t* Type;
    const wchar_t* Value;
    const wchar_t* Data;
};

int GetWhatIWant(_Out_ std::map<const wchar_t*, StructDefineInCPlus>& parameter)
{
    parameter[key1].Type = L"Type1";
    parameter[key1].Value = L"Value1";
    parameter[key1].Data = L"Data1";

    parameter[key2].Type = L"Type2";
    parameter[key2].Value = L"Value2";
    parameter[key2].Data = L"Data2";
}
```

Then I have a simple C++ wrapper class, it defines like this:

```
struct StructDefineInWrapper
{
    const wchar_t* Type;
    const wchar_t* Value;
    const wchar_t* Data;
};

int GetWhatIWantWrapper(_Out_ std::map<const wchar_t*, StructDefineInWrapper>& parameter)
{
    return m_object->GetWhatIWant(parameter);
}
```

I tried to define the struct in the wrapper as:

```
struct StructDefineInWrapper
{
    String^ Type;
    String^ Value;
    String^ Data;
};
```

But it has the error: `a member of non-managed class cannot be a handle.`

In C#, I define it like:

```
 struct StructDefineInCSharp
 {
    public String Type;
    public String Value;
    public String Data;
 }

 var myMap = new Dictionary<string, StructDefineInCSharp>();

 wrapper.GetWhatIWantWrapper(myMap);
```

But it keeps to give me the errors like cannot convert the c# defined map into the C++ map.
I never study C# before, so far I only find out that how to marshal the wstring as output parameter(which is using `String^` and `StringToHGlobalUni`), but for struct in the map, I cannot find any ways to do that.

Comment: 1) `String^` is legal syntax in C++/CLI, not in C++. 2) You are talking about "errors", but never, actually, provide the errors that you receive.

Comment: Try in c#  IntPtr since c++ is using pointers.

Comment: A map in c++ is something completely different to a dictionary in c#, you obviously can't marshall one to the other directly.